# RewriteRule with two parameters in reverse order

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got this rule

RewriteRule ^(english|hebrew|russian)/(.*).php $2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

But for the URI `http://www.google.com/hebrew/volume.php?ss=1`
it gives me `http://www.google.com/hebrew.php?lang=volume&ss=1`
Which is somewhat correct, but parameters switched. What I want to get is:
`http://www.google.com/volume.php?lang=hebrew&ss=1`

How do I preserve language, skip folder and see all the parameters preserved?

Comment: That is an internal redirect, you should still be able to access `$_GET['lang']` and `$_GET['ss']` have you tried it?

Comment: Do you have other rules somewhere?

Comment: Prix: no luck, Jon: no other rules

Comment: Is there a `hebrew.php` file somewhere?

Comment: @JonLin nops. That's just a language name, like "Serbian". Can't make file for every language to workaround :)

Comment: @alemjerus: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^(english|hebrew|russian)/([^.]+)\.php$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Dunno then, your rule works fine for me in a blank htaccess file